# Xamarin.Forms Custom Control AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have installed a NuGet package containing some Custom Xamarin.Forms Controls and added its CardStackView to the default Xamarin.Forms App template under `ItemsPage.xaml` with the following piece of XAML

```
<swipecards:CardStackView
   x:Name="CardStackView"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackLayout Padding="10">
         <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
         <Label Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" />
       </StackLayout>
     </DataTemplate>
   </swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
</swipecards:CardStackView>
```

When I run the app, however, I get an Ambiguous Match Exception in the generated code `ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs` on the following line:

`CardStackView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::SwipeCards.Controls.CardStackView>(this, "CardStackView");`

I'm really unsure how to go about debugging this. Is it something I'm doing wrong? It seems, from the exception name, like the code is confused about which of two different objects it should be accessing... There is a warning in `ItemsPage.xaml.cs` saying that there is ambiguity over which `InitializeComponent()` method needs to be called.

Comment: Are you using XF3?

Comment: @Johannes I believe so, yes.

Comment: Maybe it's connected with https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2632 :/

Comment: @Johannes Seems like it's probably related, but if I don't use the swipecards package and just create a ListView with the same Bindings, everything works as expected...